# Issue with stored procedure and COUNT IF statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement, count

So I need to make a stored procedure called AddComment, that will add a comment to my Comments table , then add an entry into the Commenters table if that commenters name does not exist.

```
 DELIMITER //                                                                                                        
 CREATE PROCEDURE AddComment(Name VARCHAR(60), Title VARCHAR(60), Comments VARCHAR(60))                              

 BEGIN                                                                                                               

 INSERT INTO Comments(Name, Title, Comments)                                                                         
 VALUES (Name, Title, Comments);                                                                                     

 DECLARE name_count INT;

 SELECT COUNT(Name) INTO name_count                                                                                  
 FROM Commenters                                                                                                     
 WHERE Name = Name;                                                                                                  
 IF name_count = 0                                                                                                   
 THEN INSERT INTO Commenters(Name)                                                                                   
 VAlUES(Name);                                                                                                       
 ELSEIF name_count = 1                                                                                               
 THEN INSERT IGNORE Commenters(Name)                                                                                 
 VALUES(Name);                                                                                                       
 END IF;                                                                                                             
 END;                                                                                                                
 //
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version fo
r the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE name_count INT;
SELECT COUNT(Name) INTO name_count
FROM Commenters

^ Is the error I'm getting. I keep tweaking my code trying to figure it out, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need a cursor to use syntax like that, but you can use SET:

```
SET name_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) ...);
```

Or better yet, since you don't actually use the value, eliminate the variable entirely:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ...) THEN
```